# Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'Daily_Services' have the same primary key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, invalidoperationexception

When I try to save this entire nested Object with the red marked object. However, it works well excluding the red marked object. If I add red marked object then through the 'System.InvalidOperationException was caught' exception.

[image]

then the following exception through

[image]

Comment: Daily_Services is list or single object? If it is list then why it is not in [ ]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/353913/hasibul vi single object

Comment: Is that object Id is guid or identity or only int?

Comment: @Hasibul vi, i just pass data through this 'Daily_Services' relational with OT_Sub_BNSB table in entity no ObjectState defined. means no changes defined for Daily_Services.